# Something is wrong with my bubble sort output

Tags: c, bubble-sort

This is just a normal bubble sort code, but something is wrong in it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubble_sort(int size, int *arr);

int main(void)
{
    int *array, size;

    printf("enter the amount of data: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    bubble_sort(size, array);

    for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(int size, int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
            else if (arr[j] == arr[j + 1])
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute it, a zero appear in the output when it must be print `1 2 3`

```bash
[my_username@my_computer bubble_sort]$ ./bubble_sort 
enter the amount of data: 3
3 1 2
0 1 2 3
^
|
Where are this zero came from?
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)` here condition should be `i < size`.

Comment: One error is here `for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j) { if(arr[j] > arr[j + 1])`. `arr[j + 1]` is an out of bounds array access when `j` is at it's maximum value.

Comment: You can also double the speed by using `for(int j = 0; j < size - i; ++j)`. Every `i` loop pushes the largest remaining element to the end and you don't have to look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not quite [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

To start, as pointed out in the comments: `arr[j + 1]` accesses the array with an invalid index - one past the end of the array when `j` is at its maximum value (`size - 1`).

The loop to print the array

```
for(int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
```

has a similar *off-by-one* error. `i < size` is the desired condition.

Accessing an array out-of-bounds invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

The `else if` block within the sort is superfluous.

---

The simplified variant of bubble sort is usually written as:

```
void bubble_sort(int *array, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas the standard bubble sort stops if it makes a pass on the array without swapping.

```
void bubble_sort(int *array, size_t length)
{
    int swapped;

    do {
        swapped = 0;

        for (size_t i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
                int temp = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}
```

This can be optimized by observing that all elements after the last swap have already been sorted.

```
void bubble_sort(int *array, size_t length)
{
    do {
        size_t n = 0;

        for (size_t i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
                int temp = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                n = i;
            }
        }

        length = n;
    } while (length);
}
```